# app works well in simulator,But crash in iphone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, audioqueue

I had developering an audioQueue Program. It's works well either simulator or iphone with xcode.
But if i lanch the app in my iphone independently,the app wil crash after 20s.
I can't get any debug information! Can anyone lead me a way to solve the problem?

Comment: The problem might be that, if you don't have a paid developer account, after  2 days from the installation on the physical device, the provisioning profiles expire. **Solutions:** ***1:*** you have to reinstall after 2 days of running on the physical device. ***2:*** Pay the developer license($99/yr) and you're good to go

Comment: It is due to IOS watch dog mechanism! the audioQueue blocking the mainQueue,I set the audioQueue asynchronize fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve crash logs by connecting your phone to iTunes on a mac and syncing it. Then in Finder choose Go > Go to folder and type `/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<your phone name>/`
There should be a list of files named after your apps

Comment: In xcode->window->Devices->my iphon->ViewDeviceLog I can find that crash log and locate the problem in watch dog,And i fix the problem use asynchronous.Thank you for your replay!